# Increase z-index on custom controls when video is fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I am working on a touchscreen video kiosk coding in javascript and CSS and HTML. I have some code that works pretty well thanks to a post by zer00ne. I have 4 videos on the page with custom controls for play and fullscreen. When I fullscreen a video I can still see the Custom controls of every other video behind it. Im not sure why but I can see that these values may have something to do with it:

```
 video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure { display:none !important; }
.vidBar1 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar2 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar3 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar4 { z-index: 2147483647; }
```

I am not a programmer by any means and I have struggled a lot just to get this this far with a lot of "borrowed" code.

What I would like to do is set the above values to 2147483646 and then on the event listener for the fullscreen button for each video have the z-index for the custom controls on that video increased by 1 on fullscreen and decreased by 1 when full screen exits. In short when 1 video is fullscreen I dont want to see anything but that video and its custom controls. 
Im not even sure if thats how it "should" be done but I'd like to get this project done as I have a limited time left to work on it and that is the last thing that is not working. Please see the entire code here and thank you so much in advance:`

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PowerHouse-VideoKiosk</title>
<style>
.vidFrame1 { position: absolute; top: 10%; width: 640px; height: auto; min-height: 180px; outline: 1px dashed red; }
.vidFrame2 { position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 50%; width: 640px; height: auto; min-height: 180px; outline: 1px dashed red; }
.vidFrame3 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 640px; height: auto; min-height: 180px; outline: 1px dashed red; }
.vidFrame4 { position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 640px; height: auto; min-height: 180px; outline: 1px dashed red; }

.vidBar1 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 40px; width: 99%; z-index: 2;}
.vidBar2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 40px; width: 99%; z-index: 2;}
.vidBar3 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 40px; width: 99%; z-index: 2;}
.vidBar4 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 40px; width: 99%; z-index: 2;}

#fullScreen1 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; outline: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 6px; display: block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 3;}
#fullScreen2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; outline: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 6px; display: block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 3;}
#fullScreen3 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; outline: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 6px; display: block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 3;}
#fullScreen4 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; outline: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 6px; display: block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 3;}

#fullScreen1:hover { border: 1px groove #0ef; }
#fullScreen2:hover { border: 1px groove #0ef; }
#fullScreen3:hover { border: 1px groove #0ef; }
#fullScreen4:hover { border: 1px groove #0ef; }

.on1, .off1 { background: url('https://glpro.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/bx/toggle.png') no-repeat; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
.on2, .off2 { background: url('https://glpro.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/bx/toggle.png') no-repeat; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
.on3, .off3 { background: url('https://glpro.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/bx/toggle.png') no-repeat; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
.on4, .off4 { background: url('https://glpro.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/bx/toggle.png') no-repeat; width: 36px; height: 36px; }

.off1 { background-position: 0 0 }
.off2 { background-position: 0 0 }
.off3 { background-position: 0 0 }
.off4 { background-position: 0 0 }

.on1 { background-position: -1px -50px }
.on2 { background-position: -1px -50px }
.on3 { background-position: -1px -50px }
.on4 { background-position: -1px -50px }

#playPause1 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; background: none; font-size: 36px; color: #0ff; line-height: 1; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; cursor: pointer; outline: none; z-index: 3;}
#playPause2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; background: none; font-size: 36px; color: #0ff; line-height: 1; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; cursor: pointer; outline: none; z-index: 3;}
#playPause3 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; background: none; font-size: 36px; color: #0ff; line-height: 1; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; cursor: pointer; outline: none; z-index: 3;}
#playPause4 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; background: none; font-size: 36px; color: #0ff; line-height: 1; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; cursor: pointer; outline: none; z-index: 3;}

#playPause1.play1:before { content: '\25b6'; }
#playPause1.pause1:before { content: '\275a\275a'; }
#playPause2.play2:before { content: '\25b6'; }
#playPause2.pause2:before { content: '\275a\275a'; }
#playPause3.play3:before { content: '\25b6'; }
#playPause3.pause3:before { content: '\275a\275a'; }
#playPause4.play4:before { content: '\25b6'; }
#playPause4.pause4:before { content: '\275a\275a'; }

.vid1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1; outline: 1px dotted blue; }
.vid2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1; outline: 1px dotted blue; }
.vid3 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1; outline: 1px dotted blue; }
.vid4 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1; outline: 1px dotted blue; }
/* 
Fullscreen Pseudo-class: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen 
*/
.vidBar1:-moz-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar1:-webkit-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar1:-ms-fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar1:fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar2:-moz-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar2:-webkit-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar2:-ms-fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar2:fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar3:-moz-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar3:-webkit-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar3:-ms-fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar3:fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar4:-moz-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar4:-webkit-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar4:-ms-fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar4:fullscreen { position: fixed; }
/* 
Special Shadow DOM Settings to Override Default Controls: 
https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/ 
*/
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure { display:none !important; }
.vidBar1 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar2 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar3 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar4 { z-index: 2147483647; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<figure class="vidFrame1">
  <video id="vid1" class="vid1" autoplay muted loop src="Bill_Nye_the_Science_Guy_S01E18_Electricity.mp4"></video>
  <figcaption class="vidBar1">
    <button id='playPause1' class="play1" title="Play/Pause Video"></button>
    <button id='fullScreen1' class="on1" title="Enter/Exit Full Screen"></button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="vidFrame2">
  <video id="vid2" class="vid2" autoplay muted loop src="Tesla'sWardenclyffeTowerandLab(3D Model).mp4"></video>
  <figcaption class="vidBar2">
    <button id='playPause2' class="play2" title="Play/Pause Video"></button>
    <button id='fullScreen2' class="on2" title="Enter/Exit Full Screen"></button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</figure>
<figure class="vidFrame3">
  <video id="vid3" class="vid3" autoplay muted loop src="IntroductiontoElectricity.mp4"></video>
  <figcaption class="vidBar3">
    <button id='playPause3' class="play3" title="Play/Pause Video"></button>
    <button id='fullScreen3' class="on3" title="Enter/Exit Full Screen"></button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="vidFrame4">
  <video id="vid4" class="vid4" autoplay muted loop src="FirstElectricBulbsbyThomasEdison.mp4"></video>
  <figcaption class="vidBar4">
    <button id='playPause4' class="play4" title="Play/Pause Video"></button>
    <button id='fullScreen4' class="on4" title="Enter/Exit Full Screen"></button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<script>

/* 
Toggle Button with classList: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList 
*/
var fullBtn1 = document.getElementById('fullScreen1');
var playBtn1 = document.getElementById('playPause1');
var fullBtn2 = document.getElementById('fullScreen2');
var playBtn2 = document.getElementById('playPause2');
var fullBtn3 = document.getElementById('fullScreen3');
var playBtn3 = document.getElementById('playPause3');
var fullBtn4 = document.getElementById('fullScreen4');
var playBtn4 = document.getElementById('playPause4');

playBtn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var player1 = document.getElementById('vid1');

  if(player1.paused) {
    playBtn1.classList.remove('play1');
    playBtn1.classList.add('pause1');
    player1.play();
  } else {
    playBtn1.classList.add('play1');
    playBtn1.classList.remove('pause1');
    player1.pause();
  }
}, false);
playBtn2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var player2 = document.getElementById('vid2');

  if(player2.paused) {
    playBtn2.classList.remove('play2');
    playBtn2.classList.add('pause2');
    player2.play();
  } else {
    playBtn2.classList.add('play2');
    playBtn2.classList.remove('pause2');
    player2.pause();
  }
}, false);
playBtn3.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var player3 = document.getElementById('vid3');

  if(player3.paused) {
    playBtn3.classList.remove('play3');
    playBtn3.classList.add('pause3');
    player3.play();
  } else {
    playBtn3.classList.add('play3');
    playBtn3.classList.remove('pause3');
    player3.pause();
  }
}, false);
playBtn4.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var player4 = document.getElementById('vid4');

  if(player4.paused) {
    playBtn4.classList.remove('play4');
    playBtn4.classList.add('pause4');
    player4.play();
  } else {
    playBtn4.classList.add('play4');
    playBtn4.classList.remove('pause4');
    player4.pause();
  }
}, false);

fullBtn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var tgtEle1 = document.querySelector('.vid1');
  var  onOrOff1 = fullBtn1.classList.contains('on1');

  if (onOrOff1) {
    enterFS(tgtEle1);
    fullBtn1.classList.remove('on1');
    fullBtn1.classList.add('off1');
    vid1.muted = false;
    vid1.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn1.classList.add('on1');
    fullBtn1.classList.remove('off1');
    vid1.muted = true;
    vid1.currentTime = 0;
  }
}, false);
fullBtn2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var tgtEle2 = document.querySelector('.vid2');
  var  onOrOff2 = fullBtn2.classList.contains('on2');

  if (onOrOff2) {
    enterFS(tgtEle2);
    fullBtn2.classList.remove('on2');
    fullBtn2.classList.add('off2');
    vid2.muted = false;
    vid2.currentTime = 0
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn2.classList.add('on2');
    fullBtn2.classList.remove('off2');
    vid2.muted = true;
    vid2.currentTime = 0
  }
}, false);
fullBtn3.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var tgtEle3 = document.querySelector('.vid3');
  var  onOrOff3 = fullBtn3.classList.contains('on3');

  if (onOrOff3) {
    enterFS(tgtEle3);
    fullBtn3.classList.remove('on3');
    fullBtn3.classList.add('off3');
    vid3.muted = false;
    vid3.currentTime = 0
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn3.classList.add('on3');
    fullBtn3.classList.remove('off3');
    vid3.muted = true;
    vid3.currentTime = 0
  }
}, false);
fullBtn4.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var tgtEle4 = document.querySelector('.vid4');
  var  onOrOff4 = fullBtn4.classList.contains('on4');

  if (onOrOff4) {
    enterFS(tgtEle4);
    fullBtn4.classList.remove('on4');
    fullBtn4.classList.add('off4');
    vid4.muted = false;
    vid4.currentTime = 0
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn4.classList.add('on4');
    fullBtn4.classList.remove('off4');
    vid4.muted = true;
    vid4.currentTime = 0
  }
}, false);
/*
Fullscreen API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API
*/
function enterFS(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
}

function exitFS() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: You should really consider dynamically  generations the video players with javascript. Your code right now is quite a complicated mess, if you generated the players with javascript it would be really short and clean. Not really an answer but it would make your code a lot easier to update :)

Comment: Yeah Im sure it would unfortunately I dont think I have the time it would take to do that before I can no longer work on this project. The code wont need to be updated it will run as is for its lifetime. I know its a mess and as I continue to learn how to actually code I plan do doing things like you mention. But like I said I only have a limited time to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate he amount of duplicate code in here... nevertheless here is what you need to do. The .vidBar classes you identified are the issue. They are always on a much higher z-index than everything else. You don't notice it though until you open the video at fullscreen. What you want to do is onl apply the high z-index to the opened video. So to do that we need to toggle a new class that is added and then removed when it is opened/closed.

```
.vidBar1.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar2.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar3.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar4.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
```

and in your JS do this:

```
  if (onOrOff1) {
    enterFS(tgtEle1);
    fullBtn1.classList.remove('on1');
    fullBtn1.classList.add('off1');
    fullBtn1.parentElement.classList.add('open');
    vid1.muted = false;
    vid1.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn1.classList.add('on1');
    fullBtn1.classList.remove('off1');
    fullBtn1.parentElement.classList.remove('open');
    vid1.muted = true;
    vid1.currentTime = 0;
  }
```

Note, this is the new part:

```
fullBtn1.parentElement.classList.add('open');
...
fullBtn1.parentElement.classList.remove('open');
```

Do that for all four, make sure you update the class name as you update each.

So the high z-index class targets the video caption, which is the parent element of the full-screen button.

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/gRxPYo?editors=0110

Good luck.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you so much for tolerating my crappy code! I just replaced 
.vidBar1 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar2 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar3 { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar4 { z-index: 2147483647; }

with your code 
.vidBar1.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar2.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar3.open { z-index: 2147483647; }
.vidBar4.open { z-index: 2147483647; }

and in the JS added 

fullBtnX.parentElement.classList.add('open'); 
and
fullBtnX.parentElement.classList.remove('open');
appropriately

ISSUE RESOLVED!!!! thanks again